# What is the best way to open an 80GB iPod classic?

Tags: ipod

I'm looking for the best way to open an iPod classic, meaning taking it apart. Mine got wet and now doesn't work and I would like to open it up and check that everythin's in place. I would like to do so in the safest way, so as not to dent the iPod. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you can tell us what country you're in, someone might have a suggestion for a local vendor. Otherwise, we'll just be guessing.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to this with tools found at any home...

Comment: You're not likely going to find one, at least not without doing damage. There's a reason iFixit (and others) have produced custom tools for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is the [plastic opening tools](http://www.ifixit.com/Tools/Plastic-Opening-Tools/IF145-000) and follow this [iFixit guide](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Repair/Installing-iPod-4th-Generation-or-Photo-Battery/393/1).

Comment: I don't have the tool and can't get it (don't sell it where I am)... any other suggestions?

Comment: @nayish I believe you may find one, at any shop selling electronic equipment/tools. At least something similar..

Comment: I'm not in the u.s...

Answer (score 1):

I've had good luck opening iPods with guitar picks in the past without damaging them. You can put them in the side crack and use them as a lever if you are gentle with it. See here:
[image]
<sub>(source: [nuxx.net](https://nuxx.net/gallery/d/87044-4/IMG_4124.jpg))</sub>